# Convert logical matrix to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, logic

So I have a 2D logical matrix of 0's and 1's, and I want a vector that is 2xn where n is the number of 1's in the matrix. In the 1st line of the vector I want the index across the lines of the matrix, and in the 2nd line I want the index across the columns of the respective "1". I could do this with cycles but I have alot of matrixes so I'd rather not.

Comment: @GastónBengolea Make that an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html) is what you are looking for:

```
A = [1 0 0; ...
     1 0 1; ...
     0 1 0];

>> [i,j] = find(A)

i =

     1
     2
     3
     2

j =

     1
     1
     2
     3
```